# Why does meteor spawn lots of child processes

Tags: meteor

Why does meteor spawn lots of child processes?

looking at a htop on a server that is hosting a meteor application

i can see about 9

/root/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/bin/node /home/panorama/panorama/panorama-demo/.meteor/local/build/main.js --keepalive

6 
/root/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/bin/node /root/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/meteor.js

and about 16

/root/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/mongodb/bin/mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --smallfiles --port 3002 --dbpath /home/panorama/panorama/panorama

Is this normal or there is something wrong with my app?

Comment: I guess thats normal. It has services like watching file changes, the mongodb if you dont use your own and the work as nodejs server itself. Lots of processes do not mean that they have a heavy load. I could not figure our more, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor is built as a toolkit and includes the node js process to run meteor and mongodb

The first is the instance of meteor your app will use.

The second is the meteor tool you use in the command line `meteor` which will be used to `run`/`deploy`/`mongo`, etc with your app

The third is mongodb which meteor uses with your app to store your data

This is all normal and is just run for you by the meteor tool to make running your app very easy.